# "Стирание" ImageView (Android)

Tags: android

Есть *xml* код:

```
ImageView
android:id="@+id/spltr"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

С помощью *Java* кода я получаю координаты касания:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
    int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();
```

Как можно реализовать стирание *ImageView* по типу: провёл пальцем и в этом месте стирается кусок картинки?

Comment: попробуйте вот эту ссылку https://www.google.ru/search?q=android+draw+on+bitmap&oq=android+draw+on+bitmap&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.18908j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=android+draw+line+on+bitmap&safe=off

Comment: Я пробовал рисовать прозрачную линию, не получается